# Displaying WMS layer in React Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, javascript, wms, react

I am trying to display a layer on top map based on parameter
**layerName, layerReference, minx, miny, maxx,maxy(bbox).**

I am not able to display the layer

This is my code

```
<WMSTileLayer {...map}/>

  const map ={
    url:"http://localhost:8080/getlayer?",
    layers:"isostatic",
    transparent: true,
    format: 'image/png',
    bbox: [-4735627.5,-8964730.0,4806772.5,-559430.0],
    layerReference:o_78_isostatic
  }
```

This is the api I have I am trying to implement in leaflet

```
    http://localhost:8080/getlayer?layerName=isostatic&crs=EPSG:3857&minX=-4735627.5&minY=-8964730.0&maxX=4806772.5&maxY=-945530.0&width=300&height=700&layerReference=o_78_isostatic
```

Comment: 88080 is not a valid port number :) you almost certainly meant 8080 or something

Comment: Any errors in the browser debugger console and/or network section?

Comment: @BarryCarter sorry typo mistake

Comment: @TomazicM I am getting 400 error

Comment: Do you get this error if you use URL from your question directly in browser?

Comment: @TomazicM, Yeah

Comment: Then here I can't help you since I'm not some expert in WMS service.

Comment: @TomazicM, I am not if it WMS service http://localhost:8080/getlayer?layerName=isostatic&crs=EPSG:3857&minX=-4735627.5&minY=-8964730.0&maxX=4806772.5&maxY=-945530.0&width=300&height=700&layerReference=o_78_isostatic, Is there is chance I can use tilelayer for this ?

Comment: Since I'm also not Geoserver guy, I can't advise you here either.

Comment: What do you get from just http://localhost:8080/ -- do you see the geoserver welcome message?

Comment: The API call you have is not a valid WMS request, a correct request would look like `http://localhost:8080/getlayer?layers=isostatic&crs=EPSG:3857&bbox=-4735627.5,-8964730.0,4806772.5,-945530.0&width=300&height=700&transparent=TRUE&version=1.3.0&request=GetMap&styles&format=image/png&BGCOLOR=0xFFFFFF&`

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

```
    {rasters.map((raster, index) => (
       <LayersControl.Overlay name={raster.name} key={index}>
            <WMSTileLayer
                  url="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/{workspace}/wms"
                  params={{
                           format:"image/png",
                           layers:"{workspace}:{layername}",
                           transparent: true,
                         }}
            />
        </LayersControl.Overlay>
    }
```

You just need to replace it with your data. Of course, you need to have the "rasters" variable created with all the information you need, I'm getting from the backend using axios, the "workspace" and "layername" you can retrieve from the same location also, this is up to you, this worked pretty well in my case.

For more information about the parameters, you can check [here](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-wms)